# Special Proof that golden ratio is irrational

Tags: geometry, number-theory

How can I proof that the golden ratio is irrational only by using the fact that if a number $n$ is not a square number, then its root $\sqrt n$ must be irrational.

Using this fact, I only would have to show that the golden ratio squared is not a square number. But how can one do this? I only know the typical contradiction proof for irrationality

Can anybody help? :)
Thanks!

Comment: so you want to show that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational... I'm sure you can find a good proof with a simple google search!

Comment: "I only know the typical contradiction proof for irrationality" : this is largely sufficient here.

Comment: You can also use the fact that an irrational number times a nonzero rational number and an irrational number plus a rational number are both irrational.

Comment: 5 Is not a square number so $\sqrt5$ and thus $\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$ is irrational. But the sum of any rational number such as $\frac{1}{2}$ and an irrational number is irrational. Hence the golden number is irrational.

Comment: $\phi^2=\phi+1$ and $\phi=m/n$ imply $m^2=mn+n^2$, which readily gives a contradiction.

Comment: To show that that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational, just assume that $\sqrt{5} =\frac pq$ with $p,q$ co-primes. You'll see that they would have the common divisor 5, a contradiction.

Comment: Can one proof that the square of the golden ratio is not a square number without using the fact that sqrt5 is irrational?

Comment: Any rational root of $x^2-x-1=0$ should be $\pm 1$ by Rational Root Theorem, neither of which actually are, and so $\varphi$ is irrational, or consider $\varphi=m/n$ for coprime $m$ and $n$, then $m^2-mn-n^2=0$ now do parity check.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 alternatively, this shows that $n$ divides $m^2$, hence divide $m$ since $n$ and $m$ are coprime. But this is a contradiction because it shows immediately that $m$ and $n$ are not coprime.

Comment: insipidintegrator's comment tells the complete story (+1)

Comment: Writing $x^2-x-1=0$ as $x^2-1=x$, we see that, if $x^2$ is an integer, then $x$ itself is an integer. But $x^2-1$ and $x$ have different parity, which gives the contradiction. (If you don't want to have to verify that a number and its square have the same parity, then you could instead write the equation as $x(x-1)=1$. The left-hand side is necessarily even, but $1$ is odd.)

Answer (score 2):

The following attempts to show, not that $\phi^2$ is not a square number, but that $\phi$ is irrational, without relying on the irrationality of $\sqrt 5$.

Geometrically, Euclid *Elements* XIII, 5 proves that if $AB$, in the figure below, is cut in extreme and mean ratio at $C$, and $AB$ is extended so that $AD=AC$ the greater segment, then $DB$ is cut in extreme and mean ratio at $A$ and $AB$ is the greater segment.
[image: Euclid, XIII, 5]
Doing this construction in reverse, in the next figure, yields a sequence of smaller and smaller lines cut in extreme and mean ratio. I.e, laying off $CD=CB$, the lesser segment, we get $AC$ cut in extreme and mean ratio at $D$, with $AD$ now the lesser segment. Again, laying off $DE=DA$ gives $DC$ cut in extreme and mean ratio at $E$, and so on.

Since$$BC<CA<2BC$$and hence also$$AD<DC<2AD$$and$$CE<ED<2CE$$then $BC$ does not divide $CA$, $AD$ does not divide $DC$, $CE$ does not divide $ED$, and so on indefinitely.
[image: XIII, 5 in reverse]

And since each new greater segment is more than half of the line being cut, then by Euclid X, 2 the original segments $AC$, $CB$ are incommensurable: *”If when the less of two unequal magnitudes is continually subtracted in turn from the greater, that which is left never measures the one before it, the magnitudes will be incommensurable.”*

Since the lesser segment continually subtracted from the greater never leaves a remainder that divides it, then the original two magnitudes are incommensurable, i.e. $\frac{AC}{CB}$ is not a ratio of two integers, and $\phi$ is irrational.